# strcmp(string,string) for palindrome checker

Tags: arrays, c, string

As a programming task for entry level software development in uni we are tasked with making a program that;

Lets the user input a string

Outputs the length of the string

Outputs whether or not the string is a palindrome(reads the same in both directions, i.e. racecar backwards is racecar)

Outputs the string reversed

We are using C. I have little experience in C, but C++/C# is familiar ground. C does not have regular strings.
In C, if you want to compute on a string you use a char array.
I have made a simple, working, version of the program that just uses a for loop to reverse the string, but I wanted to challenge myself by making some functions to handle the different parts of the program.

The problem is, that the function that is meant to return a bool indicating if the string is a palindrome returns the same value no matter the input. The string reversal however, which is handled by a different function, works, as indicated by the 3rd output value. This leads me to believe there is a problem with my understanding of `strcmp` or that I don't fully understand what my code does to manipulate the strings.

Examples of inputs and outputs from testing.
Input:
`bob`
Output:
`The word contains 3 letters The word is not a palindrome The word reversed is 'bob'`
Here the code SHOULD output that `bob` IS a palindrome, indicating that the comparison did not run correctly.
Input:
`fish`
Output:
`The word contains 4 letters The word is not a palindrome The word reversed is 'hsif'`

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Reverses a string, Takes the string, a pointer to allocated memory and the length of the substring to be reversed
void stringReverse(const char s[], char *mem, int n) {
    char b[n + 1];
    b[n + 1] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = s[n - (i + 1)];
    }
    strncpy(mem, b, n);
}

//Checks if 's' is a palindrome
bool isPal(char s[], char *c) {
    stringReverse(s, c, (int)strlen(s) + 1);
    //printf("%s", s); //used for debugging
    return !strcmp(c, s);
}

int main() {
    char word[100];
    gets(word);

    //This loop used alone works. Calling strcmp(word,rev) in place of isPal(word,c) as well as replacing c with rev in line 38.
    //    char rev[(int)strlen(word)+1];
    //    for(int i = 0; i<=(int)strlen(word);i++){
    //        if(i==(int)strlen(word)){rev[i]=0;continue;}
    //        rev[i]=word[(int)strlen(word)-(i+1)];
    //    }

    char *c = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    printf("The word contains %d letters\n", (int)strlen(word));
    printf("The word is%s a palindrome\n", isPal(word, c) ? "" : " not");
    stringReverse(word, c, (int)strlen(word));
    printf("The word reversed is '%s'\n", c);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first of all you should edit your output example. bob is a palindrome.

Comment: `stringReverse(s,c, (int)strlen(s)+1);` -> `stringReverse(s,c, (int)strlen(s));`

Comment: @kaylum The returned string in that case would not be null-terminated, resulting in further issues. This was a different problem i just not fixed with help from my prof.

Comment: @muhammedoğuz The output examples were actual tests i ran. I know bob is a palindrome, but the code outputs "not".

Comment: @muhammedoğuz that's the problem: "The problem is, that the function that is meant to return a bool indicating if the string is a palindrome returns the same value no matter the input."

Comment: `gets` has been flagged obsolete for some 25-30 years and was completely removed from the C language 9 years ago. Why are you still using it? Your source of learning must be completely outdated.

Comment: `char b[n+1]; b[n+1]=0;` is immediately wrong, since it creates an array with n+1 elements and sets the (n+2)th. (Remember, indexing is zero-based.) There may be other problems.

Comment: @Ry- Nice catch, should've seen that myself, did nothing to fix the problem though.

Comment: @Lundin That may be the case, but it doesn't have anything to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: `s[n - (i+1)]` is correct when `n` is the length of the string, but it isn’t, because it’s actually `strlen(s) + 1`. I recommend writing this without the extra array `b` so it’s simpler to follow (write directly into `mem`).

Comment: … but I also recommend writing this without string reversal, allocation, etc. entirely. Think of how you can write a function `bool is_palindrome(char const* s)` that uses a constant amount of memory (i.e. no [variable-length] arrays and no `malloc`).

Comment: You can do the reverse using the input memory and check for palindrome at the same time

Comment: The `stringReverse` function could be simpler: `mem[n]=0; for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) mem[i]=s[n-i-1];`. The extra array `b` isn't needed. Also, do not use `gets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `b[n + 1] = 0;` stores 0 beyond the end of the array
- `strncpy(mem, b, n);` does not null terminate the destination array. Don't use `strncpy`, its semantics are confusing and error prone. Since the block returned by `malloc()` is uninitialized, the byte at offset `b[n]` is not necessarily 0, hence causing `strcmp()` to return non 0.
- `stringReverse(s, c, (int)strlen(s) + 1);` uses the wrong value for the number of bytes, you should not even pass the number of bytes, just use `strlen(s)` inside `stringReverse`.
- `gets()` is deprecated and unsafe. It has been removed from the latest versions of the C standard. Do not use `gets()`, use `fgets()` or `scanf()` instead.

Note that the reversed string can be stored directly into the destination array.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Reverse a string:
//   takes a pointer to a source string and a pointer to a destination array.
//   the destination array must be long enough.
//   the source and destination array must not overlap.
//   returns a pointer to the destination array (like strcpy)
char *stringReverse(char *dest, const char *src) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[len - (i + 1)];
    }
    dest[len] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

//Checks if 's' is a palindrome
bool isPal(const char *s) {
    char tmp[strlen(s) + 1];
    stringReverse(tmp, s);
    //printf("%s", s); //used for debugging
    return !strcmp(tmp, s);
}

int main() {
    char word[100];

    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", word) != 1)
        return 1;

    int len = strlen(word);
    printf("The word contains %d letters\n", len);

    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        printf("The word is%s a palindrome\n", isPal(word) ? "" : " not");
        printf("The word reversed is '%s'\n", stringReverse(p, word));
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `bob`

Output:

```
The word contains 3 letters
The word is a palindrome
The word reversed is 'bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

As your output prints the reversed string correctly, you can assume the function `stringReverse()` works as it should. In your code you have two calls of the function:

1. In `main()` the printed result is correct:

   ```
   stringReverse(word,c,(int)strlen(word));
   ```
2. But in `isPal()` you have issues:

   ```
   stringReverse(s,c, (int)strlen(s)+1);
   ```

Remove the `+1` from the latter call and you should be ok:

```
   stringReverse(s,c, (int)strlen(s));
```

As others have mentioned, there could be better approaches to the problem, however.

Comment: Like mentioned in the questions, I already have a simple working version of the task, i am complicating it on purpose to challenge myself and learn. I will go over your suggestions and check if it works.